# how to save ui state on suspending Windows phone 8.1 rt xaml c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I found basic pages for suspend an app on windows phone 8.1 but I didn't find how to save UI state on suspending. I'm making an audio player app which have in mainpage a grid which I display or not and it contains media buttons, thumbnail, slider etc. When app is forced to suspend itself and I reopen it, it restart like first opening so it lose the app state. How can I save all app state?

Answer (score 0):

Bind all relevant UI States to some object (aka `ViewModel`) and serialize these states upon suspending.

The basic page template also includes methods like `SaveState` and `LoadState` including a serialized dictionary, where you can store those values.

Another option is to set the page's `NavigationCacheMode` to `Enabled` or `Required`. This will keep the page in memory until your app is terminated.

Comment: it is already set in this way, but in lockscreen app is killed by system.. I have only a background audio task to keep alive and application ui

Comment: Is it really killed, or does it crash? What is the 'LastExecutionState' in your 'OnLaunched' method? You Can debug suspension using the App Lifecyclebdropdown from the toolbar.

Comment: During Debug Mode if i suspend end restore it works, also in lockscreen app calls next music and it plays correctly, but when I tried without debug i found out that it's killed for some reason, I am using Windows 10 mobile, but I don't think this is the problem. 

My app contain two "projects" a Runtime Component with its background audio task and a project xaml c# which contains a mainpage and its .cs.

Comment: I use background audio messages and foreground messages to communicate data between the two components and when "media_ended" i call next track sending to foreground a message which returns next track, I can't handle musics list and lib from background, and i need to keep alive mainpage activity. It's really a big problem if i need to rewrite it totally, it's already in the store and I found out that problem to late.

Comment: please help it's really a big problem

Comment: Can You post some code, or a sample to reproduce your problem?